# Spin-resolved current

Tags: soft-question, terminology, quantum-spin, electric-current

What is spin-revolved current?
Is it the spin current?

Comment: C'mon, give us a bit of context here. Where have you heard of "spin-resolved currents", and which conflicting definitions are given? What is "the spin current" in this context?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I have to agree.  I don't think I have any expertise in this area, but even if I did, there is not enough of a question here to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Spin-resolved current in the context of scanning probe  methods means that due to a finite magnetisation of probe and sample the current consists of electrons of one spin in a larger quantity than of the other.

Spin current usually refers to current that consists exclusively of electrons of one spin direction.

Comment: It'd be slightly more accurate, I guess, to say, that spin current is the difference of current carried by electrons of one spin and current carried by electrons of the other.

Comment: @t0xic: thanks for your answer. 
Im reading the book "Semiconductor Spintronics and Quantum Computation-Springer Berlin Heidelberg (2002)". In the section 2.6.1, multiprobe model for ballistic spin transfort, I found the word "spin-resolved current". Normally, I only know the spin current, represents for the current which has 1 direction spin. but in this case they use the word "spin-revolved current", and they calculate the electrochemical potential difference between the contacts by use the formula:  $mu$up - $mu$ = 2e*Rs*Iup
where Rs is Sharvin resistance between 2 contacts.

Comment: cont.   
It's written that, in the above formula, the factor of 2 arise because transport is spin-resolved. Therefore, I think spin-resolved current is different with spin current. But I can not find a clear definition of spin-resolved current.